# Error: must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'Variable' in this scope

Tags: c++, c++14

I am getting [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylGXd.png)
Code I have so far

//operand.cpp

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#include "expression.h"
#include "subexpression.h"
#include "operand.h"
#include "variable.h"
#include "literal.h"
#include "parse.h"

Expression* Operand::parse(istringstream& iss) {

    char paren;
    int value;

    iss >> ws;
    if (isdigit(iss.peek())) {
        iss >> value;
        Expression* literal = new Literal(value);
        return literal;
    }

    if (iss.peek() == '(') {
        iss >> paren;
        return SubExpression::parse(iss);
    }
    else {
        return new Variable (parseName(iss));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

//expression.h

```
#ifndef EXPRESSION_H
#define EXPRESSION_H

class Expression {
public:

    virtual int evaluate() = 0;
};
#endif
```

//subexpression.h

```
#ifndef SUBEXPRESSION_H
#define SUBEXPRESSION_H

#include "expression.h"

class SubExpression : public Expression {
public:

    SubExpression(Expression* left, Expression* right);


    static Expression* parse(istringstream& iss);

protected:
    Expression* left;
    Expression* right;

private:


    static Expression* determineType(char operation, Expression* left,
        Expression* right);
};
#endif
```

//operand.h

```
#ifndef OPERAND_H
#define OPERAND_H

#include "expression.h"

class Operand : public Expression {
    int Variable;

    //public static method
public:static Expression* parse(istringstream& iss);
};
#endif
```

//variable.h

```
#ifndef VARIABLE_H
#define VARIABLE_H

#include "operand.h"

class Variable : public Operand {
public:

    Variable(string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    int evaluate() override;

private:
    string name;
};
#endif
```

//literal.h

```
#ifndef LITERAL_H
#define LITERAL_H

#include "operand.h"

class Literal : public Operand {
public:

    Literal(int value) {
        this->value = value;
    }

    int evaluate() override {
        return value;
    }

private: int value;  // value declared as  data type integer.
};
#endif
```

//parse.h

```
#ifndef PARSE_H
#define PARSE_H

string parseName(istringstream& iss);
#endif
```

When I build the project I get must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'Variable' in this scope on operand.cpp at else {
return new Variable (parseName(iss));

Please guide me what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: coincidentally just some minutes ago an answer was posted to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129983/why-write-a-class-in-the-declaration-of-a-class-object explaining exactly that case

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129983/why-write-a-class-in-the-declaration-of-a-class-object

Comment: You have `int Variable` member, that hides the class Variable in that scope.

Comment: Do not delete the body of the answered question.

Comment: That looks like a LOT of code for a compilation error. A [mre] would have helped guide both you and us to the cause.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like meaning the name `Variable` is anbiguous between the class `class Variable` and the member variable `int Variable;` of class `Operand`.

Since the member variable doesn't look used, it should be deleted. If you want to use that later, it should be renamed (for example, `int variableId;`, maybe)

Comment: Why is the following the compiler advise and use `new class Variable` not an option?